# Curvature and Torsion of a Curve

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, curves, differential, frenet-frame

I am currently working on a problem and think I know the answer but need verification. The question reads:

> Let there be a curve with non-zero curvature and zero torsion. Show this curve is planar. If the curve is allowed zero curvature at one point, does this above statement still hold?

I have shown that the curve is planar with non-zero curvature and zero torsion. But when the curve has zero curvature $\textit{and}$ zero torsion, isn't the curve a straight line there? And if so, doesn't this straight line remain in the original plane normal to the constant $\boldsymbol b$?

Comment: What does it mean for a curve "to be a straight line a particular point"?

Comment: Doesn't it just mean that it remains straight and doesnt curve at all?

Comment: The point is that the notion isn't well-defined.

Comment: So I can just say that it is impossible to have a straight line at just one particular point, therefore the curve is not planar?

Comment: The curve certainly *can* be planar. For example, the graph of $x \mapsto x^3$ is planar but its curvature vanishes at exactly one point.

Comment: But it doesn't hold in general?

Comment: Suppose you were looking for an example of a curve $C$ with zero torsion and curvature vanishing at a single point: Since you know that the if the curvature is nowhere zero the curve /is/ planar, each of the two halves of the curve (the parts on each side of the point where the curvature vanishes) is planar. So, to build a counterexample, you'd need to take two planar curves and glue them together at a single point in such a way that the two curves aren't in the /same/ plane.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$f(t)=\begin{cases}(t,t^3,0)&t\leq 0\\(t,0,t^3)&t\geq 0\end{cases}$$ 
Here $f$ has zero torsion but is not planar. It has zero curvature only at $t=0$.

Comment: Yes I am aware, but I am wondering what happens to the curve if it is allowed zero curvature at one single point.

Comment: Oh, then I totally change my answer

Comment: Though to be honest I am not sure how the torsion is defined at $t=0$.

Comment: Ah I see. Is there a general theorem or a statement I can use to simply state that if it has zero curvature at a point it is not planar?

Comment: @Travis Yes, I was wondering this also, is the intention of the problem that curvature is zero at some point and thus that torsion is undefined there ? How are the normal and binormal at such a point to be defined ? I think you have to specify these things before attempting to find a better counterexample or a proof.